# Is there a way to run CMD command as is using c# without splitting it to filename and arguments?

Tags: c#, cmd, process, freeze

I'm working on a SW that parses file with commands and it needs to execute all the commands .
Looking thourgh StackOverFlow i found the following snippet:

```
String command = @".\wrap.exe sys";
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // You can start any process, HelloWorld is a do-nothing example.
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = command; 
    myProcess.Start();
    string output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();

}
```

For some reason the command `myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` hangs if i run it(Even if i change the order of this command and this command `myProcess.WaitForExit()` and the standard Error output command also hangs(any ideas why this commands hangs?).

If i change  `FileName = "CMD.exe"` to `FileName = "wrap.exe"` and `Arguments ="sys"` it will work.
The problem is that i don't want to split it to arguments and fileName. Is there a way to do so(e.g. in Python using subprocess) ?

Comment: Have you tried to add `/c` before `wrap.exe`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski no it didn't help

Comment: @Magnetron No it doesn't . I looked at it before i posted the question